# Manipulating Date with Conditional Statements

Tags: r

I'm trying to add and subtract days from my date-time but facing some issues.

**Reproducible Example**

```
df = data.frame(date1=c("2017-07-07", "2017-02-11", "2017-05-22")) 

library(lubridate)
df$date1 <- ymd(df$date1) + years(2)
df$day <- wday(df$date1, label=TRUE)

df$date1 <- as.Date(df$date1, "%Y-%m-%d")
df$day <- as.character(df$day)
```

**Data**

```
       date1 day 
1 2019-07-07 Sun   
2 2019-02-11 Mon       
3 2019-05-22 Wed
```

**Problem**

I'm trying to get my code to work in a manner that when the day is "Sunday", it will simply copy the same date. However, my code above returns "18084" instead of "2019-07-07".

Could someone explain to me where my issue is?

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(newdate = ifelse(day == "Sun", as.Date(as.character(date1), "%Y-%m-%d"), 1))

       date1 day newdate
1 2019-07-07 Sun   18084
2 2019-02-11 Mon       1
3 2019-05-22 Wed       1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is you are trying to return objects of two different class in `ifelse`. If you check

```
str(df)
#'data.frame':  3 obs. of  2 variables:
# $ date1: Date, format: "2019-07-07" "2019-02-11" "2019-05-22"
# $ day  : chr  "Sun" "Mon" "Wed"
```

So `date1` is of class "Date" and the else part in your `ifelse` contains 1 which is numeric. So now to bring both of them to the same class what R does is

```
as.numeric(as.Date("2019-07-07"))
#[1] 18084
```

Dates are anyway represented internally as numbers. For example,

```
as.Date(18084, origin = "1970-01-01") #would give
#[1] "2019-07-07"
```

What you probably need is

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(newdate = ifelse(day == "Sun", as.character(date1), "1"))

#       date1 day    newdate
#1 2019-07-07 Sun 2019-07-07
#2 2019-02-11 Mon          1
#3 2019-05-22 Wed          1
```

but this will change `newdate` to character class.